# east asian language is broken when I make Executable in DrRacket(language is scheme)

Tags: scheme, executable, racket

I'm using DrRacket for Scheme Programming.

for I'm not a person who use native English, I need to print out east asian language.

There is no problem when I press run button in IDE.

East asian language is printed well.

But when I make an executable file, and execute, east asian characters were broken when program prints out.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bug.  Please ask this on the [Racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).

Comment: is there any way to fix this problem right now? but ask to mailing list? Thanks anyway~!

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but I see that you posted on the mailing list, so the people who will know better will probably say something.